# How to change the mtime of the directory and its files in perl?

Tags: linux, perl

I want to change the modification time (mtime) of the directory and all its files recursively. I tried this -

```
utime(undef, 1396396800, "/X/Y/dir1");
```

dir1 contains more directories and files, the above statement only changing the mtime of /X/Y/dir1 only , not other directories/files inside /X/Y/dir1.

Is there any method wich can recursively change the mtime of directory in the perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "recursively change mtime" function. You'll have to implement it yourself with `File::Find`.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub change_mtime {
    utime( undef, 1396396800, $File::Find::name );
}

find( \&change_mtime, "/X/Y/dir1" );
```

(I'm assuming your `utime` example is correct, I haven't tested it)

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs.